# How to convert a numbered list to circled digits in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I see that Google Docs has settings for customizing types of numbered lists, such as these settings::

[image: Google Docs numbered list customizers]

[image: More Google Docs numbered list customizers]

But I’m being asked to make all the numbered lists use the circled-type numbers, known as “circled digits” such as with the UTF "CIRCLED DIGIT ONE”

So my list should look like:

[image: circled digit list]

I can’t figure out how to do this. I can add custom bullet points with any character, but those, as bullet points, just repeat the same character for all items in the list.

I would love some way to either set the document’s numbered list to use this format (and then I can save it as a template), or even some way to make the document with a normal numbered list, then convert it somehow.

Right now, I’ve just been using keyboard shortcuts to convert my typed (1) into ①, etc. But of course those don’t follow the nice auto-indentation that a formatted list has.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> But I’m being asked to make all the numbered lists use the circled-type numbers, known as “circled digits” such as with the UTF "CIRCLED DIGIT ONE”

### Spoiler

I am not aware of a font in Google Docs that allows you to do this although there are ~1500 available so maybe one exists.  If you are willing to use MS Word there is a font available that will do what you want.

### Circled Number Lists in Google Docs

- you should use a font as opposed to a symbol or Unicode in order to maintain the ordering
- the font used needs to have circled numbers in place of regular numbers (or letters)
- the font needs to be one of the fonts already included/supported by Google Docs

I am not aware of a Google Docs font that fits the bill however if you turn up a name of one that might work, you can compare it to the list of ~1500 fonts available in Docs.  The free [Extensis Fonts Add-On](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/extensis_fonts/568288816452) can make font name searching in Google Docs easier.

### Circled Number Lists in MS Word

Microsoft Word 365 has more built-in functionality around list styles and can additionally leverage fonts installed on your PC which Google Docs does not do.

I found an OpenType (`.otf`) Windows font called [Numberpile](https://www.dafont.com/numberpile.font) that is made up of circled numbers.  The font is free and released under a Creative Commons [CC0 1.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/) that allows you unfettered use even for commercial work.

### MS Word: Approach 1

This approach leverages OpenType standard ligatures which enables creating circled numbers with this font by surrounding the number in parentheses. For example, typing **`(1) (2) (3)`** will map to [image]

- While the **`(#)`** custom format can be defined, the font cannot be applied as part of that as it seems that within the Define Format tool it is unable to interpret **`(#)`** as anything but 3 separate characters
- Fortunately, it is not a lot of work to apply the font formatting when you insert the first **`(#)`** formatted bullet.
- Word will then remember the font for subsequent lists
  [image]

### MS Word: Approach 2

This 2nd approach uses the mappings in the 'Numberpile Guide' included in the downloaded font package (also shown at the bottom). For example, **`A B C D`** maps to [image]

- when using this approach, the custom Number Format you define in Word should be set to start by default at **`B`**, since **`A`** maps to [image]
- so [image] would be mapped from **B C D**

### Document Sharing: Doc / Word

If you are sharing the document with Google Doc and MS Word users, remember that they are unlikely to have the Numberpile font installed.

- Depending on the approach used, they will see **`(1) (2) (3)`** or **`B C D`**  instead of [image]
- Given that, it is best to use approach 1 as `(#)` will allow lists to start at **`(1)`** instead of **`B`**

### Document Sharing: PDF

If distributing the document via PDF, the circled numbers will **always display correctly**, regardless of the approach used.

### Images

<sub>**Define a Number Format**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Approach 1 - PDF (Font not Required)**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Approach 1 - MS Word (Font not Installed)**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Approach 2 - PDF (Font not Required)**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Approach 2 - MS Word (Font not Installed)**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Character Mapping Guide**</sub>
[image]